# Unable execute POST query with inserted JSON data over CURL

Tags: json, curl

I need to create POST query to application ( https://exampleapp.com/ms/auth ) over CURL utility. But query is:

```
login=MyLogin&password=MyPassword&firstEnv=0&SecondEnv={"device_id":"23","device_os":1,"device_os_version":"1.2.3","a
pp_version":"2.3(4)"}
```

How i can do this via CURL utility (Windows) ?

Answer (score 1):

1. put the entire thing you want to post into a file, call the file 'blob.txt'
2. invoke `curl -d @blob.txt https://example.com/blabla/bla`

Comment: Daniel, hi!
What string format contains in blob.txt?

Comment: The file would contain exactly what you want to send. curl will strip off newlines afair

Comment: No, i mean, what is correct curl string? If i use jsonm then i execute: curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d 'MYJSONFORMAT' http://hostname/resource

If i need execute standart POST query, i try:
curl --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://hostname/resource

But i need perform standart POST query with inserted JSON data, like this:
login=MyLogin&password=MyPassword&firstEnv=0&SecondEnv={"device_id":"23","device_os":1,"device_os_version":"1.2.3","a
pp_version":"2.3(4)"}

What is correct CURL string?

Comment: That's what my answer says. You put the whole "login=MyLogin... bla blabla" (without my added quotes) into blob.txt and off you go. Then use --trace or --trace-ascii to verify exactly what is sent.